# PHP SQL Loop results based on field

Tags: php, sql, loops

I am creating a dynamic recordset where I populate a couple values to the query used to select all inked records.

Next I need loop and group the results but am unsure how to group by the values used in the query.

Reference query:

```
SELECT fldItem, fldDescription, fldRank,fldType FROM tableName
WHERE fldType IN (33, 34, 36) ORDER BY fldRank
```

The values 33,34 and 36 are going to be passed dynamically to the query.
My goal is to then have a loop/repeat region that allows display in groups with all the results that share the same fldType

Results should look like this:

```
item1, description1, rank1, type33
item2, description2, rank2, type33
item3, description3, rank5, type33
item4, description4, rank6, type33
item5, description5, rank8, type33

--------

item6, descriptionv, rank1, type34
item7, descriptionw, rank2, type34
item8, descriptionx, rank3, type34
item9, descriptiony, rank4, type34
item10, descriptionz, rank5, type34

--------

item11, descriptionA, rank2, type36
item12, descriptionB, rank3, type36
```

using a do / while loop does displays all the items to display but not with any grouping. Is a ForEach loop the solution?

Comment: Have you tried different SQL statements with a GROUP BY? That would return the results in groups. You could then use a loop and when the Type changes, have it drop out a line break, or whatever you want to distinguish the different types.

Comment: GROUP BY does *not* return the results in groups, it returns a single result for a group. I.e., using GROUP BY here would result in getting just three rows back.

Comment: Yes initially I was trying GROUP BY but found it not working when used with the selection IN ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about a visual grouping in your report output, then you'll need to track that value for each loop iteration, and then issue your visual break when you detect a change. Something like this:

```
$last_type = null;
foreach ($records as $record) {
    if ($last_type !== null && $last_type != $record->fldType) {
        echo '<whatever your visual cue is>';
        $last_type = $record->fldType;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you do:

```
ORDER BY fldType, fldRank
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fldItem, fldDescription, fldRank,fldType FROM tableName
WHERE fldType IN (33, 34, 36) ORDER BY fldType, fldRank
```

This will group by fldType first, then by fldRank. In your PHP code, just remember the last fldType, and add a new group whenever it changes. All fldTypes will be grouped together now, so you can just loop through the results in order.

Comment: Yes, this returns the results in the manner referenced above but I am trying to get groups such as displayed by the "--------" breaks. In actual conditions this is because the results (each group) are to be set to a formatted table.